# BucketRegionError: incorrect region, the bucket is not in 'eu-west-2' - terraform

Tags: terraform

I need terraform to access my S3 bucket, but it is not able to find the bucket on the specified region.

My main.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-west-2"
}

terraform {
    backend "s3" {
        bucket = "xyz-state-blog"
        key    = "dev/terraform"
        region = "eu-west-2"
    }
}

locals {
    azs                     = ["eu-west-2a", "eu-west-2b", "eu-west-2c"]
    environment             = "dev"
    kops_state_bucket_name  = "${local.environment}-kops-state"
    // Needs to be a FQDN
    kubernetes_cluster_name = "k8s-dev0.domain.com"
    ingress_ips             = ["10.0.0.100/32", "10.0.0.101/32"]
    vpc_name                = "${local.environment}-vpc"

    tags = {
        environment = "${local.environment}"
        terraform   = true
    }
}

data "aws_region" "current" {}
```

following is the error which I'm getting on `terraform init` command:

```
Error inspecting states in the "s3" backend:
BucketRegionError: incorrect region, the bucket is not in 'eu-west-2' region
  status code: 301, request id: , host id:
```

Comment: Have you created the bucket already? Terraform does not create the bucket.

Comment: yes the bucket is created, also checked the default creds of .aws region is also same

Comment: Then, make sure the bucket was created in the 'eu-west-2' and make sure sure that Terraform is using the 'default' profile. Also, your terraform backend does not have a locking mechanism, typically, I do it this way: terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "${TF_VAR_state_bucket}"
    dynamodb_table = "${DYNAMODB_STATE_TABLE}"
    key    = "terraform/$STATE_PATH/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "$REGION"
    encrypt = "true"
  }
}

Comment: which version of terraform are you using I'm using Terraform v0.11.13
It's giving me an error `terraform.backend: configuration cannot contain interpolations` maybe because of the version

Comment: Sorry, I was using a BASH to generate the backend. My point being that you need a DyanamoDB Table for locking the state so that multiple people can work without stepping on each other, and you want to encrypt it so that sensitive values can be protected. You might also want to use default encryption on the bucket.

Answer (score 18):

For me removing the **.terraform folder** and trying `terraform init` again solved the region related issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

no need to remove the whole .terraform folder:

1. find your `.terraform/terraform.tfstate`
2. remove json object responsible for `S3` bucket
3. remove the stanza generating remote backend
4. run `terraform init` & enjoy

error is appearing apparently because there's no S3 bucket created to sync with.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and wasted a lot of time on it, I thought I'd share my experience it might help others.

It almost always happens when you are defining the aws "region" in a place other than where you think you have it defined and that other definition overrides the value that you think you have defined.

In my case it was in the ~/.aws/config profiles, some may find it in ~/.aws/profile.

You can make sure that you're getting the right value by either one of these two methods:

1. export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<region> # from the command line. Or:
2. if you are using terraform/terragrunt, [here is the order of precedence](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#variable-definition-precedence)

Answer (score 0):

no need to remove the whole .terraform folder:

First find the correct region in which bucket exists and after that you can reconfigure terraform by using `terraform init -reconfigure` command and it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue on my side was that I did not specify the region in my aws provider block.

Somehow after I set it to `us-east-1` and used `terraform init -reconfigure` as suggested by @Dhruv Modi, the error no longer occurred.

If it helps anyone, here's how I specified the region in my provider block:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"

  # ...
}
```